# Bison parser choking on "incomplete" expression

Tags: parsing, grammar, bison

I've written a parser in bison (in yacc-mode), and now I'm trying to implement some kind of "incomplete" (but valid) instructions.

The grammar is somewhat complex, but the relevant part is:

```
script:
  input { root = createScript($1); }
  ;
input:
  statement
  | input statement { $$ = createSequence($1, $2); }
  ;
statement:
  S_SEMICOLON { $$ = createNode(); }
  | declaration S_SEMICOLON { $$ = $1; }
  | assignment S_SEMICOLON { $$ = $1; }
  | command S_SEMICOLON { $$ = $1; }
  | compound S_SEMICOLON { $$ = $1; }
  | block S_SEMICOLON { $$ = $1; }
  ;
declaration:
  (...)
block:
  S_LTRACKET input S_RTRACKET { createBlock($2); }
  | S_LTRACKET input { createIncomplete($2); }
  ;
```

(LTRACKET is '{' and RTRACKET is '}')

For some reason I can't understand the first "block" gets parsed correctly, and the second one doesn't. If I parse "{ int i = 7; stdout(i); }" it works, but if I try to parse "{;" it stops with a "syntax error".

The debug output doesn't say a lot:

```
Starting parse
Entering state 0
Reading a token: Next token is token S_LTRACKET ()
Shifting token S_LTRACKET ()
Entering state 40
Reading a token: Next token is token S_SEMICOLON ()
Shifting token S_SEMICOLON ()
Entering state 38
Reducing stack by rule 9 (line 135):
   $1 = token S_SEMICOLON ()
-> $$ = nterm statement ()
Stack now 0 40
Entering state 54
Reducing stack by rule 2 (line 126):
   $1 = nterm statement ()
-> $$ = nterm input ()
Stack now 0 40
Entering state 78
Reading a token: Now at end of input.
Error: syntax error
Error: popping nterm input ()
Stack now 0 40
Error: popping token S_LTRACKET ()
Stack now 0
Stack now 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have a shift/reduce conflict you're not dealing with.  When you run bison, you see an error message like:

```
parser.y: conflicts: 1 shift/reduce 
parser.y:20.5-39: warning: rule useless in parser due to conflicts: block: S_LTRACKET input
```

if you look at the .output file you get from `bison -v`, you see something like:

```
state 15

    3 input: input . statement
   10 block: S_LTRACKET input . S_RTRACKET
   11      | S_LTRACKET input .

   ';'  [reduce using rule 11 (block)]
```

the default shift/reduce resolution in favor of shift means that it will never reduce the block rule without the closing brace.  This conflict comes from the ambiguity over an input like `{ { ; }`, which can be parsed as either a block containing an incomplete block, or an incomplete block containing a block.

Now you might ask "Why is this happening when there's not an extra set of braces?  Surely the parser's one-token lookahead should see the EOF and decide to reduce instead of shift?"  That would in fact be the case if you used an LR(1) parser generator, but bison (and yacc) use LALR(1), which combines states that only differ in lookahead.

Also, the grammar doesn't accept what you say it does -- your example input `{ int i = 7; stdout(i); }` will cause a syntax error due to the missing final `;` (after the `}`).  You could change the `statement` rule to get rid of the `;` after the `block`, in which case you'll get even more shift/reduce conflicts, but it will at least accept the inputs you say you want it to accept.

Comment: You are right, it doesn't (but the language has a simple preprocessor which appends a semicolon to every line in interactive mode).

Comment: Anyway, the "incomplete" part is now gone, and everything works now, the preprocessor can also check unbalanced braces. Thanks.

Comment: This isn't quite correct, for what it's worth. You can tell bison to produce a canonical LR grammar, and it will report exactly the same SR conflict, because the grammar as presented is not LR(k). The issue is that a block, and hence an incomplete block, needs to be followed by a semicolon. An incomplete block, however, needs to end with a semi-colon, because `input` needs to end with a semi-colon. Consequently, `{;` is not a valid sentence. `{;;` is, and the SR conflict comes after the first `;` in `{;;`: both `{;;};` and `{;;` are valid programs, but after the `{;` you can't tell which.